# Random ComException with VB.net Excel Automation

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have done quite a bit of research on this issue and haven't came up with anything definitive yet.  I am having issues with Excel randomly getting ComExceptions while writing out reports.  I am using a Visual Basic 2005 (framework 2.0) console application to create these reports.  The problem has been difficult to figure out because it occurs in random places while writing out reports so I can't catch the error to see the problem.  I have looked through the differing items that it breaks on and there is nothing odd about them that would cause any of these problems.

Also, sometimes the report runs fine without any problems.

stack trace:
(15:27:24:247)     Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
(15:27:24:247)     Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
(15:27:24:253)     Stack Trace:    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMemb
er(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes,
MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Value(Object RangeValueDataType,
Object )
Error Code: -2146777998

Comment: VBA_E_IGNORE, very unpleasant.  It is a re-entrancy problem, Excel is waiting internally for an operation to complete.  While waiting, it couldn't help to get your request but can't execute it because it is busy.  Retrace your steps, consider what you asked it to do before it went belly-up.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (without seeing your code) is that you might be falling foul of the way COM objects are released when used through .NET interop. See [this article](http://www.getdotnetcode.com/gdncstore/free/Articles/ReleasingComObjectsWithVbNet.htm) for a quick introduction.

Essentially, what can happen is that all the COM objects your code creates are actually wrapped in a .NET object. These .NET objects ultimately get disposed of by the garbage collector at unpredictable times. When they're disposed, the underlying COM object is released. In some circumstances, this can cause a crash where the underlying COM object has already been destroyed by Excel by the time the garbage collection happens.

Driving Office from .NET is many times more difficult than driving it from older technologies like VB6 precisely because of this issue. (Another problem you'll likely hit is the Excel process not terminating - you'll see lots of questions about that on SO).

PS. To get started, search for ReleaseComObject on SO...